# Simple evolutionary string matching

Tags: python, strings, random

This is based on a very similar question I asked, found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49780/change-random-list-of-numbers-into-all-5s-using-simple-evolution-simulation).

The intent of this program is to start with a set number of random strings of zeros and ones, and eventually evolve them to find one specific string (`'111111'`).

It fulfils its purpose, but what do you think, and how can I improve it?

```
import random as r
import operator
import time
import os
target = '111111'

class String(object):
    def __init__(self, chromo):
        self.chromo = chromo
        self.fitness = 5
        self.age = 0
def Fitness(string):
    for char in string.chromo:
        if char == '1':
            string.fitness += 1
        else:
            pass

def SelectParents(strings):
    parents = []
    parents.append(max(strings, key=operator.attrgetter('fitness')))
    strings.remove(parents[0])
    parents.append(max(strings, key=operator.attrgetter('fitness')))
    strings.append(parents[0])
    return parents  

def PartStringRand():
    string_complete = ''
    for _ in range(4):
        rand = r.randint(0, 1)
        string_element = str(rand)
        string_complete = ''.join([string_complete, string_element])
    return string_complete

def CreateChild(strings, parents):
    for children in range(2):
        string_complete = PartStringRand()
        string_complete += (parents[0].chromo[r.randint(0, 5)] + parents[1].chromo[r.randint(0, 5)])
        child = String(string_complete)
        strings.append(child)

def KillOld(strings):
    for _ in strings:
        if _.age > 2:
            strings.remove(_)

#First strings
strings = []

for _ in range(5):
    string_complete = ''
    for _ in range(6):
        rand = r.randint(0, 1)
        string_element = str(rand)
        string_complete = ''.join([string_complete, string_element])
    string = String(string_complete)
    strings.append(string)
    if string.chromo == "111111":
        strings.remove(string)
for string in strings:
    print string.chromo
raw_input()


#Start incremental mutation
c = 0
for _ in range(5000000):
    #os.system("cls")
    for string in strings:
        Fitness(string)
    parents = SelectParents(strings)
    CreateChild(strings, parents)
    for organism in strings:
        organism.age += 1
        print organism.chromo
        if organism.chromo == '111111':
            print "::...Successfully evolved specifc string '111111' from random strings...::"
            time.sleep(4)
            sys.exit()
    KillOld(strings)        
    c += 1
    print "Generation: %s" %c
    #time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: *"I believe it fulfills [sic] its purpose"* - have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, it does work. Sorry for being too ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing that immediately jumped out:

```
def KillOld(strings):
    for _ in strings:
        if _.age > 2:
            strings.remove(_)
```

`_` is used by convention to indicate "I won't be using this variable", e.g.:

```
for _ in range(5):
    do_something()
```

If you *are* using the variable, give it a better name (even just `s`). Also, functions' names should be `lowercase_with_underscores` per [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

---

Next, your mutation seems odd, as it generates four new random characters then picks two from the parents. Instead, I would have done:

```
def create_child(parents):
    return String("".join(r.choice(c) for c in zip(*(p.chromo for p in parents))))
```

i.e. for each position, pick randomly between the two parents.

Note that the function returns the new `String`, rather than adding it to `strings`. I would say that:

```
strings.append(create_child(parents))
```

is clearer than adding to `strings` as a side-effect. Similarly, I would probably rewrite `KillOld` to return a new list, rather than mutate its argument (and call it `kill_old`).

---

You can simplify

```
string_complete = ''
for _ in range(6):
    rand = r.randint(0, 1)
    string_element = str(rand)
    string_complete = ''.join([string_complete, string_element])
string = String(string_complete)
```

to:

```
s = String("".join(map(str, (r.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(6)))))
```

(don't use `string` as a variable name; you may want to use that module later). And rather than `append` then `remove` it, check first:

```
if s.chromo != target:
    strings.append(s)
```

(**Note** that you define `target` then don't use it - replace all `'111111'` with `target` and you can change it much more easily in future!)

---

Rather than calculate the `s.fitness` for each `s`, then have a complex `key`:

```
parents.append(max(strings, key=operator.attrgetter('fitness')))
```

make the function `fitness` that takes a single `String` and *returns* the fitness score:

```
def fitness(s):
    return sum(c == t for c, t in zip(s.chromo, target))
```

Your `key` is then e.g.:

```
parents.append(max(strings, key=fitness))
```

This also decouples the fitness from the `String` object itself; you no longer need the `s.fitness` attribute.

---

You could also generally improve `SelectParents`; `remove` and `append` again is not efficient.

```
def select_parents(strings):
    return sorted(strings, key=fitness)[-2:]
```

This sorts `strings` in ascending fitness, then returns a sliced list of the last (up to) two items.

Comment: Good answer, I will take into consideration your suggestions.

Comment: @FrigidDev no problem; I've just added another comment

Answer (score 0):

I second jonrsharpe's answer. In addition...

Python function names conventionally begin with lower case: `fitness`, `select_parents`, etc. `UpperCase` is for classes.

Calling a class `String` is confusing, because of the built-in string type. How about `Organism`?

`Fitness` should be a function (or a method `Organism.fitness`) returning a fitness. It should **not** modify the organism! Anyway, there's a simpler way to do it: `return self.chromo.count('1')`.

`SelectParents` should not modify its argument. In general, don't use state unless you *mean* state.

What's the point of `sleep` before `exit`? Just finish.

In the main loop, `c` duplicates the loop variable. They can be combined: `for generation in range(1000000):`...